# Describing and comparing illustrations: is it a fit for the site?

Tags: support

I was wondering if someone with little knowledge of the fundamentals of graphic design could ask a question along the lines of:

*Can the technique used in this drawing(ink pen) from a professional artist be briefly summarized/categorized and is it similar to what is seen in this other work?(showing details for both)*

- Is it about illustration, or more generally, is it within the *scope* of the site?
- Is it *interesting* for the community on the site?
- If not, do you know of an SE asset *where* this works?

Comment: Thank you for the answers!

Answer (score 1):

It's not "My Adobe isn't working" so I say.. yes... it's on topic and will at least break up the monotony of those wanting help with software.

Comment: I use Gimp anyway ;)

Answer (score 0):

I think it is – with good examples, I think these kind of questions would be quite interesting. It might be about placing visuals in historical, artistic context and I for one would like to see more questions about the bigger picture of what we do.

Comment: Admittedly I know nothing about the history of art but I think the first thing I can do is to properly identify(attribute) the time where the work was created and read a bit about the artist.

Answer (score 0):

I would just make the question and tag it [style-identification](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/style-identification) and [illustration](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/illustration). If we don't like it we'll remove it.

My worry is to not have [style-identification](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/style-identification) become as horrendous as [font-identification](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/font-identification). If the question is even remotely similar to a typical font-id question (no effort on your part) then I'll be the first to down-vote and close-vote it.

Comment: I've taken a look at the font-identification content and I understand. I don't think it would be like that. What I'm trying to avoid on the contrary is too wide a scope and/or too many subquestions...